# Help showing $\phi _k$ is a bounded linear functional

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be the space of continuous functions on the interval $[-\pi , \pi]$ with the $L^2$ norm $$\lVert f\rVert_2=\left(\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|^2\mathrm dt)\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$ For $f$ in $V$, define $$\phi_k(f)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos(kt)\mathrm dt$$ I want to show $\phi_k$ is a bounded linear functional on $V$ and find the norm $\lVert \phi_k\rVert$ of $\phi_k$ as a linear functional on $V$.

Showing $\phi_k$ is linear is easy. But I get lost trying to show boundedness. Here's what I have to show boundedness: $$|\phi(f)|=\frac{1}{\pi}\left|\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t)\cos(kt)\mathrm dt \right|\le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)||\cos(kt)|\le \lVert f\rVert\lVert g\rVert =\sqrt{\pi}\lVert f\rVert.$$

I let $g=\cos(kt)$, then I used the norm above and got $\sqrt{\pi}$. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are on the right track. Notice that we can choose $f(t):=\cos(kt)$ (remember the case of equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So am I missing anything in showing boundedness? How do I find the norm $||\phi_k||$?

Comment: No you didn't miss anything. Maybe you could just mention Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Davide, How do I find the norm $||\phi_k||$ of $\phi_k$ as a linear functional on $V$? Do I use the definition of sup? Thanks

Comment: You computed it in the answer.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I think you have to use Hölder's inequality; the bound seems to be incorrect.